# Can sstableloader run from a node where Cassandra is not installed or the package is not installed?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to bulk load TBs of data into a live target Cassandra cluster. I came across the Cassandra sstableloader tool. I am trying to load an existing SSTable back into a cluster. The first approach I tried was to map SSTables to the nodes on the target cluster and run sstableloader. However, is there a way to run sstableloader from a remote node where Cassandra is not running or where Cassandra package is not installed ?

An orthogonal question is, is it good to bulk load data from the same node where the target live cluster is running ?

Comment: your SSTables are accessible from Cassandra node?

Comment: sstableloader is included in the binary download for Apache Cassandra so you can run it on a different node, however, you will need to have a configured yaml file for the target cluster. You said you tried to map SSTables? Can you explain more?